gsub recognizes my regex only in perl mode
Can somebody explain which part of my regex is PERL specific? I do not understand why R's default regex engine does not capture the titles in this string?
gsub("^[\\w.-]+\\.\\s|\\s[\\w.-]+\\.$", "", "Dipl.-Ing. Jerzy Textor MBA.")
# [1]  "Dipl.-Ing. Jerzy Textor MBA."

gsub("^[\\w.-]+\\.\\s|\\s[\\w.-]+\\.$", "", "Dipl.-Ing. Jerzy Textor MBA.", perl = TRUE)
# [1]  "Jerzy Textor"


[\w.-] is the culprit, \w is treated as a backslash and w instead of a "word" class. Simply replace with [:alnum:]_: gsub("^[[:alnum:]_.-]+\\.\\s|\\s[[:alnum:]_.-]+\\.$", "", "Dipl.-Ing. Jerzy Textor MBA.")

Ah so easy and  thanks for the linked article very informative and I learned a lot +1 (more if I could ;)

Just note that \w with (*UCP) matches more than [A-Za-z0-9_]. [:alnum:]_ is a rough approximation of a PCRE \w.

Wow, needed to ask ChatGPT what (*UCP) means but agaun very enlightening. Thanks!

Also see my answers, here or here.
